# Get the key values using jq from json

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, jq

I am looking for a way to find the full key path for given value taken from the variable. My input comes from the elasticsearch query result.

For example I want a full path to the key value: **9i6O4ERWWB** 
They key value is always unique and what only changes is the example.com and template1 keys (I cannot predict what will be the name).

Once knowing the key path: 
**_source.example.com.template1**  I want to increment the "counter" field and update the elasticsearch document.

My input JSON:

```
{
    "_index": "domains",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "c66443eb1e6a0850b03a91fdb967f4d1",
    "_score": 2.4877305,
    "_source": {
        "user_id": "c66443eb1e6a0850b03a91fdb967f4d1",
        "statistics": {
            "test_count": 0,
            "datasize": 0,
            "example.com": {
                "template1": {
                    "image_id": "iPpDWbaO3YTIEb0pBkW3.png",
                    "link_id": "4ybOOUJpaBpDaLxPkz1j.html",
                    "counter": 0,
                    "subdomain_id": "9i6O4ERWWB"
                },
                "template2": {
                    "image_id": "iPpDWasdas322sdaW3.png",
                    "link_id": "4ybOOd3425sdfsz1j.html",
                    "counter": 1,
                    "subdomain_id": "432432sdxWWB"
                }
            },
            "example1.com": {
                "template1": {
                    "image_id": "iPpDWdasdasdasdas3.png",
                    "link_id": "4ybOOUadsasdadsasd1j.html",
                    "subdomain_id": "9i6O4ERWWB"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried was:

```
<myfile jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1])
<myfile jq -c 'paths | select(.[-1] == "subdomain_id")'
```

but this prints all apart the key values:

```
["_index"]
["_type"]
["_id"]
["_score"]
["_source"]
["_source","user_id"]
["_source","statistics"]
["_source","statistics","test_count"]
["_source","statistics","datasize"]
["_source","statistics","example.com"]
["_source","statistics","example.com","template1"]
["_source","statistics","example.com","template1","image_id"]
["_source","statistics","example.com","template1","link_id"]
["_source","statistics","example.com","template1","subdomain_id"]
["_source","statistics","template2"]
["_source","statistics","template2","image_id"]
["_source","statistics","template2","link_id"]
["_source","statistics","template2","subdomain_id"]
["_source","statistics","example1.com"]
["_source","statistics","example1.com","template1"]
["_source","statistics","example1.com","template1","image_id"]
["_source","statistics","example1.com","template1","link_id"]
["_source","statistics","example1.com","template1","subdomain_id"]
```

My pseudocode I am trying to write:

```
seeked_key_value="432432sdxWWB"
jq -n --arg seeked_key_value "$seeked_key_value" \
'paths | select(.[-1].$seeked_key_value'
```

Expected result:   `["_source","statistics","example.com","template1","subdomain_id":"432432sdxWWB"]`

Is this doable with jq in bash?

Comment: why `template2` is not inside a key like the other templates ? is this the expected behavior ?

Comment: My fault, should be. Editing.

Comment: Okay! in this case i will post my answer as i was trying to figure out the missing key issue :D

Comment: I have produced a nasty workaround away from JQ in the meantime that I am ashamed to post.

Comment: until this moment this is working for me, `jq '._source.statistics | .[] | objects | .[] | select(.subdomain_id=="432432sdxWWB")' test1.json` , i am working on adding the parameter

Comment: I see. But with this we do not have access to the full key path in case you want to modify it. Unless you do not need and can do modification on place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'extract' paths using the following:

```
jq -c 'paths(scalars) as $p | [$p, getpath($p)]' file.json | grep 432432sdxWWB
```

and response is:

```
[["_source","statistics","example.com","template2","subdomain_id"],"432432sdxWWB"]
```

Possibly you can improve jq query to get only single value but I hope it helps you in determining final version :)

Comment: Perfect Maciek! That helps a lot to simplify the code!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to avoid `grep` in cases like this.  To meet the exact requirements in the present case, one could write:

```
jq -c 'paths(scalars) as $p
| [$p, getpath($p)]
| select(.[1] == "9i6O4ERWWB")' input.json
```

If one really needs grep-like functionality, you can always use jq's `test/1`.